# django many2many field make not required

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a form based on a model. The model has a many2many field. I defined the field like this:

```
contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True, null=True)
```

I`m wondering now why the generated form says that this field cannot be blank. I always get the error message "This field is required.", when i do not select a contact for the contacts field.

Whats`s wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form declaration mark this field as `required=False`

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  contacts=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Contact.objects.all(),required=False)
  class Meta:
    model=MyModel
```

Comment: do you know if I want to filter the contact with restriction that it should display only related to current instance of form, I mean it should display contacts related to Business not all. for new form should be empty, queryset=Contact.objects.filter(Contact.objects.filter(self.instance.????)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you did `syncdb` before adding `blank=True, null=True`?

`syncdb` will only create tables if they don't exist in the database.  Changes to models have to be done manually in the database directly with SQL or using a migration tool such as [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Of course, if you are still in early development, it will be easier to drop the database and run `syncdb` again.

Comment: No I did run syncdb. I also did run django evolution http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/. 
I thought also that this is the problem. Maybe a drop is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of null=True is confusing here.  A manyToMany field results in a 3rd table relating one model to another.  e.g.

```
Business <-> Contact
```

If `business.contacts` is empty, no records are entered into this table.  `null=True` would make me think you are intending for `NULL` records to be added to this table, which doesn't seem valid.

Typically you would leave *both* of these attributes off.

Comment: Ok but if i leave both of these attributes off, they are required. Actually it is not a big problem if the user has to add at least one m2m relationship, but it still would be interesting how this could be accomplished.